# Java 1.7.0_45 Update and Eclipse Helios incompatibility issues

Tags: java, eclipse, helios

Anyone else getting this error after Java update to 1.7.0_45 ?

running Eclipse Helios on Windows 8 - x64

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: At the very least use `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6`

Comment: what does your .ini file look like?

Comment: What's the drawback of using a newer version of Eclipse?

Comment: Are you using a 64b JRE/JDK and 64b Eclipse? Using different versions will cause issues. See http://superuser.com/questions/246863/running-32bit-eclipse-on-64bit-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting Fredrik comment:

> Are you using a 64b JRE/JDK and 64b Eclipse? Using different versions will cause issues. See superuser.com/questions/246863/…

This is due to versions incompatibility.